# Why does Pages force me to waste the last line in the page?

Tags: pages, text-editor

In the short video below, I'm trying to place the "CIS 256" in a new line below the paragraph ending with "MLQRT". But Pages refuses, insisting that the last line in the page, just below "MLQRT", should be unused. Why ?

[image]

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain his or her reasons ?

Answer (score 4):

This occurs because of a pagination option called "Prevent widow & orphan lines". By default, Pages prevents the first or last line of a paragraph from appearing on the bottom or top of a page and separating it from the rest of the paragraph. These lines are called [widows and orphans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans).

To disable this, select the text. Then, under the Format sidebar on the right side of the window, click the More tab and uncheck "Prevent widow & orphan lines."